# How to extract value using request url

Tags: php, html

My `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is something like /advt/upload/siteid/1. I need to retreive that '1' from the specified path. How can I do preg match or anything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the last path segment? Easy!

```
$lastPathSegment = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/N37TJ0mh).

You may want to use `rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')` to ensure the path doesn't have a trailing slash.

There are many other ways to do it. Assume `$uri = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')`...

```
$lastPathSegment = end(explode("/", $uri));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/na6kxRIM).

```
$lastPathSegment = ltrim(strrchr($uri, "/"), "/");
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/4eJHAyQi).

```
$lastPathSegment = substr($uri, 1 + strrpos($uri, "/"));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/D3J3mTVx).

```
$lastPathSegment = preg_replace('/^.+\//', '', $uri);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/dLSwRIgL).

...and many more.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last segment:

```
$endSegment = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Otherwise if it's not the last, but you know the index of the value

```
$pieces = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$selectedSegment = $pieces[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split function ie

```
list($sec1,$sect2,$sect3,$sect4) = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

where $sect4 is your number, or just an straight array

```
$uri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

$num = $uri[3];
```

You may also want to look at regular expressions

```
preg_match('/(?P<sect1>\w+)\(?P<sec2>\w+)\(?P<sect3>\w+)\ (?P<digit>\d+)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

see this link for more on preg matches [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: `split()` has been deprecated. Better to use `explode()`.